# JQuery Ajax Data Post Then I had to create php page in the Session

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I'm posting my data on the same page with Ajax. I create the PHP session, but the session does not occur. I codes is as follows. **I move does not seem session print_r values.** Where I do not know I'm doing wrong, please help me. Thanks everyone

JAVASCRIPT CODES

```
        $('.uk-form-reg').submit(function(e){

            e.preventDefault();
            var ad=$('#ad').val();
            var email=$('#email').val();
            var sifre=$('#sifre').val();

                $.ajax({
                type:"post",
                url:"<?=$BASEURL?>php/modules/kullanicilar.php",
                data:{"ad":ad,"email":email,"sifre":sifre},
                async: true,
                crossDomain: true,
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },
                success:function(cevap){
                    if(cevap){
                        window.location.assign('<?=$BASEURL?>soru-sor');
                    }else{
                         alert('Başarılı Değil');
                    }
                }

                });

        });
```

PHP CODES

```
if(empty($_POST)==false){


        $insert=$site->db->insert('kullanicilar',array('adi'=>$_POST['adi'],'mail'=>$_POST['email'],'sifre'=>$_POST['sifre']));

        if($insert){

            session_start();
            $_SESSION['sadi']=$_POST['adi']; //NOT WORKING
            $_SESSION['email']=$_POST['email']; //NOT WORKING
            echo(TRUE);
            exit();
        }else{

            echo(FALSE);
            exit();
        }

}
```

Comment: What does $insert return?
Looks like your code isnt entering the if statement.

Comment: Where are you trying to use the session variables? In the script from which the AJAX was executed? You will not be able to do that. Rather explain to us what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: what you are getting in $_POST. do the print_r($_POST);exit;

Comment: Saving $ successfully inserts records into the database value is not false to true is going to be successful. PHP PDO.

Comment: I am sending data with ajax, php I create the same page with the result that session but I did not create a php session with Ajax. How can I do this with AJAX?

Comment: There is no shortage of everything running on PHP, the data is only annoyance avoid post-session variable.